# climb angle of 737-800 performance

Tags: aircraft-performance

I am doing a report on 737-800 and I have questions about its climb angle performance;

I am plotting a climb angle VS altitude graph for the aircraft, why does the climb angle take off at an angle and then increase to a maximum value and then decrease again as it ascends?

Does anyone know the climb angle that the aircraft takes off at? and the maximum climb angle of the aircraft?

If could provide a factual link would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a copy of your other question, please delete it.